# While trying to append Python dict to JSON it writes only once

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am working on a Face Recognition project and want to write logs of detected faces, into a JSON file. I am using the following code.

```
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime,date

now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')
now_str = str(now)

def write_logs(time,date,name,accuracy,direction):
    a = []
    entry = {'time':time,'name':name,'accuracy':accuracy,'direction':direction}
    if not os.path.isfile('./log'+now_str+'.json'):
        a.append(entry)
        with open('./log'+now_str+'.json', mode='a+') as f:
            json.dump(a,f, indent=3)
    return a
```

The output is:

```
[
   {
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 20:39:07",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "97.22941",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]
```

However, what I was expecting is:

```
[
   {
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 20:39:07",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "97.22941",
      "direction": "default"
   },
{
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 20:39:07",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "97.22941",
      "direction": "default"
   },
{
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 20:39:07",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "97.22941",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]
```

The JSON arrays should be appended continuously, till the time my algorithm recognizes faces for the day. However, as mentioned earlier, it writes only once.

Comment: The snippet of the code from where, I am getting the values to the function write_logs is :  logger.write_logs(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S'),str(datetime.now()),unique,str(mean),'default')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RAJKIRAN VELDUR: The problem is your if-statement. According to your code, once the file exists, you cannot append to it. I believe you just need to remove `not` from your if-statement, or remove the if-statement altogether. Based on what you're trying to accomplish, you don't actually need it.

**EDIT:** The `json` module doesn't allow you to append to a file in the way that you want. The most straightforward approach will be to load and update the data each time you want to append. Like so:

```
def write_logs(time,date,name,accuracy,direction):

    entry = {'time':time,'name':name,'accuracy':accuracy,'direction':direction}

    log_file = './log'+now_str+'.json'

    if not os.path.exists(log_file):
        # Create file with JSON enclosures
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump([], f)

    # The file already exists, load and update it
    with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
        data = json.load(r)

    data.append(entry)

    # Write out updated data
    with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

    return [entry]
```

Comment: it works. However, the output is not in a proper JSON format. I got it like: [
   {
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 23:59:28",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "91.62468",
      "direction": "default"
   }
][
   {
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 23:59:28",
      "name": "Rakesh",
      "accuracy": "74.21411",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]

Comment: however, I wanted it to be: [
   {
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 23:59:28",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "91.62468",
      "direction": "default"
   },{
      "time": "13/06/2018 - 23:59:28",
      "name": "Rakesh",
      "accuracy": "74.21411",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Hi @T.Ray, I am now trying to write a code that dynamically creates a json file every day. So, made few changes to your code. However, it now prints the json object only once. Not sure if it is indentation error. Please have a look.

Comment: def write_logs(time,date,name,accuracy,direction):
    entry = {'time':time,'name':name,'accuracy':accuracy,'direction':direction}
    yesterday_log_file = './log'+yesterday_str+'.json'
    log_file = './log'+now1_str+'.json'

Comment: if os.path.exists(yesterday_log_file):
        with open(yesterday_log_file) as f:
            Date = json.load(f)
            Date1 = (Date[-1])
            Comparision_Date = Date1['time']
            a = datetime.strptime(Comparision_Date[:10],'%d/%m/%Y')
            print(a)
            now = datetime.strptime(datetime.now(),'%d/%m/%Y')
        if a == now:
            with open(yesterday_log_file, 'r') as r:
                data = json.load(r)
        data.append(entry)
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

Comment: if a < now:
            # Create file with JSON enclosures
            with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
                json.dump([], f)

        # The file already exists, load and update it
        with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
            data = json.load(r)

        data.append(entry)

        # Write out updated data
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

Comment: else:
        # Create file with JSON enclosures
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump([], f)

    # The file already exists, load and update it
    with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
        data = json.load(r)

    data.append(entry)

    # Write out updated data
    with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

    
        return [entry]