# Trying to write a python code that create a new json file every day

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm working on json logs of my face recognition model and my task is to write a code that dynamically create a new file every day. I have a code, but not sure why it writes only the first log. I want it to append continuously as long as my camera continues to recognize the faces.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import os
from pprint import pprint
import json

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday1 = datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y%m%d')
yesterday_str = str(yesterday1)
now1 = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')
now1_str = str(now1)

def write_logs(time,date,name,accuracy,direction):
    entry = {'time':time,'name':name,'accuracy':accuracy,'direction':direction}
    yesterday_log_file = './log'+yesterday_str+'.json'
    log_file = './log'+now1_str+'.json'

    if os.path.exists(yesterday_log_file):
        with open(yesterday_log_file) as f:
            Date = json.load(f)
            Date1 = (Date[-1])
            Comparision_Date = Date1['time']
            a = datetime.strptime(Comparision_Date[:10],'%d/%m/%Y')
            print(a)
            now = datetime.strptime(datetime.now(),'%d/%m/%Y')
        if a == now:
            with open(yesterday_log_file, 'r') as r:
                data = json.load(r)
        data.append(entry)
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=3)    
        if a < now:
            # Create file with JSON enclosures
            with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
                json.dump([], f)

        # The file already exists, load and update it
        with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
            data = json.load(r)

        data.append(entry)

        # Write out updated data
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

    else:
        # Create file with JSON enclosures
        with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump([], f)

    # The file already exists, load and update it
    with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
        data = json.load(r)

    data.append(entry)

    # Write out updated data
    with open(log_file, mode='w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)


        return [entry]
```

However, let me tell you, it works with a single if statement, as mentioned by @T.Ray here: [While trying to append Python dict to JSON it writes only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840778/while-trying-to-append-python-dict-to-json-it-writes-only-once/50842590?noredirect=1#comment88700874_50842590)

Comment: The solution I previously gave you will automatically create a new log file each day. What are you trying to do that my answer does not already accomplish?

Comment: @T.Ray I agree that your code already does it. However, what I'm trying to accomplish is while the inference continues for days, we don't really run the program to write the logs. In that case, we need to check the date and at midnight, we need to make the program create a new log file, implicitly.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying that you always need to create a new log file at midnight, regardless of whether you have any entries to write? Also, why do you need to check the date before creating a new log file?

Comment: @T.Ray that's right. Right at midnight, I need to create a new log file. I wrote a date comparison function, so that it will check the date and if the new date is greater than old date, it will create a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to create a new log file every day at midnight, then you should not need to compare dates.  If it is midnight, then the new date will ALWAYS be greater than the old date (i.e., yesterday). So comparing doesn't seem to make sense.  If it's a new day, `write_logs` will automatically create a new log file. Now, if you need to create a new log file (at midnight), regardless of whether you have an entry to write, then you can write a wrapper function to handle that:

```
def update_logs(args=None):

    # If no entry is passed, create new log file
    if not args:

        log_file = './log'+now_str+'.json'

        if not os.path.exists(log_file):
            # Create file with JSON enclosures
            with open(log_file, 'w') as f:
                json.dump([], f)

    else:
        # A new entry is passed, update existing log file
        write_logs(*args)


def write_logs(time, date, name, accuracy, direction):

    entry = {'time': time,
             'name': name,
             'accuracy': accuracy,
             'direction': direction}

    log_file = './log'+now_str+'.json'

    if not os.path.exists(log_file):
        # Create file with JSON enclosures
        with open(log_file, 'w') as f:
            json.dump([], f)

    # The file already exists, load and update it
    with open(log_file, 'r') as r:
        data = json.load(r)

    data.append(entry)

    # Write out updated data
    with open(log_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

    return [entry]

# Example records
entries = [("18/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default'),
           ("18/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default'),
           ("13/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default'),
           ("13/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default'),
           ("13/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default'),
           ("13/06/2018 - 20:39:07", 'whatever', "Rajkiran", "97.22941", 'default')]


# Case 1: Log file already exists, update it
now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')
now_str = str(now)

for entry in entries:
    update_logs(entry)

# Case 2: Midnight, no entries, create a new empty log file
now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1), '%Y%m%d')
now_str = str(now)

update_logs()

# Case 3: Midnight, with entries to write
now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1), '%Y%m%d')
now_str = str(now)

for entry in entries:
    update_logs(entry)
```

Calling `update_logs` will handle everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `mode='w'` to be `mode='a'`

- `w` overwrites any existing file
- `a` simply appends over an existing file (or creates one if none exist)

Lots of good info here:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. What I'm looking for is something of the sort :  '[
   {
      "time": "14/06/2018 - 07:41:47",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "91.08506",
      "direction": "default"
   },
   {
      "time": "14/06/2018 - 07:41:52",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "100.0",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]' However, if I use mode = 'a' I get: '[][
   {
      "time": "19/06/2018 - 08:48:52",
      "name": "Rajkiran",
      "accuracy": "100.0",
      "direction": "default"
   }
]'

Comment: However, let me tell you, it works with a single if statement, as mentioned by @T.Ray here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840778/while-trying-to-append-python-dict-to-json-it-writes-only-once/50842590?noredirect=1#comment88700874_50842590)